# Who is left to fight in Star Wars episodes 8 onwards?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens

Having just watched TFA for the fifth time, read the novelisation (adult only) and gone through the Visual Dictionary, something just came to me:

With the absolutely massive losses on all sides, just who and what is left to fight any Star **Wars** moving forward?

- The Visual Dictionary makes mention of the major disarmament on all sides after the defeat of the Empire
- What there was of the Republic fleet seemed to have been concentrated around the Hosnian system and was blasted to bits, as Hux had declared and intended
- We don't know what there is in terms of ground troops, or if those also were concentrated in the above system and are now floating through space
- It's made clear in all of the above sources that the Resistance operates on a shoestring and they just lost at least half their fleet of starfighters above Starkiller Base
- If they had/have any capital ships, we haven't seen one
- The First Order, similar to *< Godwin Trigger Redacted >*, secretly broke the disarmament treaties with factories and shipyards in the Outer Rim
- We've only seen one lone fancy new Star Destroyer, not even any additional ones around their precious Starkiller. Makes you wonder just how many capital ships they have overall
- Oodles of troops and TIE fighters and ground combat vehicles were on the planet/base and are now part of the coronasphere when it all went "look, new binary star system, neat!"
- Having yet again indulged the Dark Side/Sith obsession with super-expensive super-weapons, there may not be a lot left as all the funds went into this boondoggle
- The Visual Dictionary states that the FO has a fraction of the resources and funds of the Empire

With all this, what's left at the level that fits the moniker **Star** Wars?

Scattered Republic patrol craft, the odd capital ship probably mostly used for peackeeping missions, a handful of Resistance fighters, whatever capital ships the First Order was able to afford with all the cash going into SKB.

Will the title of Episode 8 be **Star Wars - The Arms Race Is ON!** ? **Star Wars - Drole du Guerre** ?

Out of universe, all sides would now need decades to lick their wounds and rebuild their fleets for another show-down. In universe, we might be tuning in again a couple years down the road to switch to Rey and Kylo (and Finn and Poe?) having picked up more Force experience points.

Comment: Snoke and the Knights of Ren are still out there.

Comment: Space is big. Like, really big. Plenty of room for ships and people to fly them at each other.

Comment: Snoke looks like he'd lose a wrestling match with Stephen Hawking. OK, this Force thing, sure, but I bet he isn't as good at math. Seriously, Palpatine and Vader still had a gigantic Imperial force behind them. No matter how strong in the Force, without that they wouldn't have rules the galaxy. BTW, where **were** all those knights?

Comment: @PaulD.Waite But also big enough to fly past each other. ;)

Comment: Uhm we saw way more than only ONE star destroyer. In the backgrounds when the one is shown above the weapons planet there were 4 or 5 nearby.

Comment: @Thomas Were there? Time to single frame that scene! :)

Comment: Luke and Rey vs. Snoke and Kylo Ren?

Comment: Going to edit my question to make clear I meant conflict at an inter-stellar level. STAR Wars, not just protagonists (Jedi or no) against each other.

Comment: When major players are removed, it creates a power vacuum where existing factions fight to gain the top dog spot. The fall of the two major factions should lead to wars at the very least. I doubt they'll play it up that way, though.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic based on our future works policy: http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/q/5187/5184

Comment: You seemed obsessed with the title. You do realize that no stars were at war in any of the other movies, right? I mean this as a serious question based on the way you stress topics and use **BOLD** letters. Stars are not ships or planets.

Comment: Meh, as serious as one can get when one is discussing scifi&fantasy. ;) In some ways it was triggered by a thread from some time ago that asked just what the Star in Star Wars meant, so I'm not the first one to wonder. That said, in this case it's a matter of ... call it military assessment. We've see major materiel losses on both sides just in one movie. Unless someone digs out the Star Forge (oh please, oh please, yes! and Revan too ;) that's gonna take some major overtime.

Comment: “Snoke looks like he'd lose a wrestling match with Stephen Hawking.” So did Yoda! “as serious as one can get when one is discussing scifi&fantasy.” Round here, that’s pretty serious.

Answer (score 1):

I think that there are plenty of ships that the Resistance has, and so does The First Order. Snoke didn't seem too bothered when Starkiller Base was destroyed and Leia seemed more upset for Rey then concerned about the fleet. There are plenty of ships to go around. Also, it isn't a fledging rebellion, working against a giant empire. Its a splinter cell fighting what is a terrorist cell.

Comment: Do you have a source for "plenty of ships"? Because that is directly contradicted by the (canon) Visual Dictionary. In several pages there is mention about the "Resistance is so undermanned", "Resistance transports cobbled together" (page 57). There were 2 squadrons on D'Qar - and from the fear about the oncoming attack, we can assume they couldn't just cram into a transport and leave. This was *it*. And now they've lost the equivalent of a whole squadron.